# Laravel 9 vite vue 3 router-view not rendering component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am using vue 3 , vite and laravel and it was working properly until I started using the router. when I'm using `router-view` its shows nothing. I tried change app.js to different ways but it didn't worked out. How can I fix it?
I tried a lot but could not find out the issue.

`login.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Login Page</title>
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This load from blade file</h1>
        <div id="app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css'; 

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import LoginIndex from './components/auth/LoginIndex.vue';


const app = createApp({
    components: {
        LoginIndex
    }
});
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');

// createApp(LoginIndex).mount('#app')
```

`router/index.js`

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import LoginIndex from '../components/auth/LoginIndex.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login.index',
        component: LoginIndex
    }
]

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

`components/auth/LoginIndex.vue`

```
<template>
    This load from vue file
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I wanted to get load each component via the router

Comment: did you run ```npm run dev```

Comment: yep, I won't work, I think this method doesn't support with vite. It may works with webpack